# How to convert a compressed base64 Image to a File or Blob for Firebase Upload (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

***Error code : "h {code_: "storage/invalid-argument", message_: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File."***

> Here's a JS code snippet of the image being compressed and converted to base64 which is then saved to Session storage to be retrieved while upoading or so is my plan.

```
function process() {
  const file = document.querySelector("#upload").files[0];

  if (!file) return;

  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  reader.onload = function (event) {
    const imgElement = document.createElement("img");
    imgElement.src = event.target.result;
    
    imgElement.onload = function (e) {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const MAX_WIDTH = 300;

      const scaleSize = MAX_WIDTH / e.target.width;
      canvas.width = MAX_WIDTH;
      canvas.height = e.target.height * scaleSize;

      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      const srcEncoded = ctx.canvas.toDataURL(e.target, "image/jpeg");

      // you can send srcEncoded to the server
      sessionStorage.setItem("image",srcEncoded);

      var image = new Image();
      console.log(srcEncoded);
      image.src = srcEncoded;
      document.body.appendChild(image); 
    };
  };
}
```

> Code snippet for when the image is taken from session storage and sent to firebase.

```
const Upbtn = document.getElementById('fileButton');

Upbtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  console.log('Upload Button');

  //Get File
  const file = sessionStorage.getItem('image');

  console.log('Grabed');

  //Create Storage reference
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/pictures/' + file);
  console.log('location');

 //Create Blob

  //Upload file 
  const task = storageRef.put(file);
  console.log('Submitted');
});
```

> Deeply grateful to everyone and this community in advance.

Comment: Have you tried send the image to firebase before it was stored in sessionstorage? At least this will eliminate or confirm the issue is sessionstorage and not something else.

Comment: I need the image to be previewed before uploading it hence session storage

Comment: Sometimes one has to do not something that need in order to troubleshoot..